# Giving scope to private procedure inside another procedure without forward declaration

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, forward-declaration

Im having a package spec without_fwd which is having public procedure p1 and p2.

Also im having package body without_fwd which is having three procedure p1,p2 and p3. Here p3 is private procedure which was created after p1 but used inside p1.

However in order to use p3 inside p1, we can use forward declaration to provide the scope.

I need to know is there any other way to provide the scope of p3 so that we can call it inside p1 without using forward declaration

```
create or replace package without_fwd is
procedure p1;
procedure p2;
end without_fwd;
/

create or replace package body without_fwd is
procedure p1 is
begin
p3;
end;
procedure p2 is
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Success');
end;
procedure p3 is
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Success 2');
end;
end without_fwd;
/
```

Comment: Other than by defining `p3` before `p1` in the package body?  Note that your example doesn't actually appear to have a forward declaration of `p3`?  Is this a homework assignment or is there some business problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Its more of like homework problem but i need to know the possibilities whether we can use the private procedure inside the public procedure without doing forward declaration or without make the p3 as public by specifing it in package spec

Answer (score 1):

For a homework assignment, I would assume the professor is just looking for you to define the private method first (which, incidentally, is generally much more common than creating a forward reference in the real world)

```
create or replace package body without_fwd 
is
  -- Private methods
  procedure p3 is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Success 2');
  end;

  -- Public methods
  procedure p1 is
  begin
    p3;
  end;

  procedure p2 is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Success');
  end;
end without_fwd;
```

If `p3` is only used in `p1`, it can be defined as a part of `p1` rather than as a private method for the package.  In the real world, this is somewhat unusual-- I've never actually seen a code base that used this approach regularly though I have talked to people that do use the approach.  I'll use it occasionally to simplify ad hoc anonymous blocks for data changes but that's about it.

```
create or replace package body without_fwd 
is
  -- Public methods
  procedure p1 
  is
    procedure p3 is
    begin
      dbms_output.put_line('Success 2');
    end;
  begin
    p3;
  end;

  procedure p2 is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Success');
  end;
end without_fwd;
```